# Bitmap Region Blocking C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am currently writing an program to Filter pictures.
To make my program faster I split a picture into multiple Regions.
To do that I block regions with the method LockBits.

```
 BitmapData data1 = inputimage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, 100), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
 BitmapData data2 = inputimage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 200, image.Width, 100), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

If I run this Code I get the Exception (if the second code line is executing), I get the exception that this region is already locked.
For me it makes no sense. This region is not blocked, but i get the message that it is.

Can anyone help me??
Marcel

Comment: Can't you just lock everything and then coordinate access yourself?

Comment: You either need to manage the sub-areas of the bitmap yourself, or operate on each sub-area one at a time, locking and unlocking before you move on to the next one. I don't think you're allowed to lock a bitmap that's already locked.

Comment: As a follow-up to what Peter Duniho says, there is no reason why you can't have multiple threads working on different areas of the same locked bits buffer.